# Why document click is not working on real android device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i'm facing problem on `android device` with `document.click` code the `code` works fine in `browser` but did not work on `android device`.

**here is my working code for `browser`(but Doesn't work on `android`):**

```
public showMoreBarItem = false;

counter:number = -1;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-user-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'user-dashboard.html',    
    host: {'(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',}                
})


onClick(event) {
  if(!(this.counter % 2 === 0)) {         
    this.showMoreBarItem = false; 
  }
}
```

please help why it is not working on `android` device

**Still i'm looking for an answer,  Please Help me, thanks in advance!!!**

Comment: The click event is not available on touch devices. Use `touchstart` or `touch` instead. I have no experience with angular, so you should figure out that part yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You might need ontouch or ontouchend, as the touch event can be different than the click event.